# In how many ways can 3 integers (not necessarily distinct) be chosen from {1 to 100} so that their sum is even

Tags: combinatorics

I dont get the solution.

```
SOLN: Case 1: 3 even. The answer is
(52C3)= 22100.
Case 2: 2 odd 1 even.
(50C1)x(51C2))= 63750.
```

Thus ans = 22100 + 63750 = 85850

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum can be even in two ways. Three even numbers or two odd numbers and one even number.

If you have $n$ distinct elements and you want to count the number of possible selections of $m$ elements with repetitions allowed, the total is $\binom{n+m-1}{m}$.

In your problem you are choosing $3$ integers, not necessarily distinct, i.e. you can choose the same number multiple times, i.e. repetitions are allowed.

Hence

$$\binom{50+3-1}{3} + \binom{50}{1} \times \binom{50+2-1}{2} = \binom{52}{3} + \binom{50}{1} \times \binom{51}{2} =85850$$

Comment: There are 50 even numbers right. Why cant i 50 Chose 1 * 50 choose 1 * 50 choose 1

Comment: @RStyle If you cared about the order in which the integers were chosen, then you would use this.